Material Library VX
I'm new to Blender and recently I realized there is an add-on that places a library with some materials in the Material tab. It's not a super long list, so I would like to find more if possible, and with some way to just look at thumbnails rather than having to apply the material. I learned Modo about 10 years ago and I remember it had a browser with the material applied to the same mesh, which made it really fast to find what you were looking for.
Is there something like that in Blender as an add-on? And a website where I can download materials to use for free?

Blender has a built-in Asset Browser which you can use for materials and all sorts of other things. Search the web for for Blender asset browser for many tutorials on how to use it. There are also many web sites online where you can download free materials but that's off-topic for this site. Best to ask on https://blenderartists.org for suggestions.

Thanks, somehow I had missed it in the list of types of areas, whatever that's called. But now that I see it I wonder if my installation is correct, because it seems that the only category in it is hair, and it's very complete, with many subcategories, but it seems odd that the regular installation would only have hair and that's it. Is that the way it's supposed to be?

Yes. That's correct. You're expected to add other categories and assets yourself although I believe that the Blender Foundation is creating a downloadable asset package. - Incorporating lots of assets within the Blender executable itself would create a huge file.

Oh, so the screenshot on this page is not there with the default Blender installation?
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/asset_browser.html

That's just an image of what it would look like once you've populated it with your assets.
